# org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not retrieve version: for entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, db2

I have @version annotation and session.lock for the same entity. I am getting org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not retrieve version: for entity exception and transaction getting rolled back. Can I use both(@version annotation and session.lock) for same entity?

```
    Sequence SequenceObj = (Sequence) session.get(
            Sequence.class, ID);
    session.lock(SequenceObj, LockMode.FORCE);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("sequenceName", "Some Name"));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("sequence",existingId));

    SequenceObj.setSequence(existingId);
    session.update(capeSequenceObj);
    session.flush();
    return existingId;
```

Comment: in pojo I have this code

Comment: In POJO class I have this below code.      @Version 
 public long getVersion() {
  return version;
 }

 public void setVersion(long version) {
  this.version = version;
 }